# Splitting a Column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split the following column using Pandas: (df name is count)

```
Location                        count
POINT (-118.05425 34.1341)      355
POINT (-118.244512 34.072581)   337
POINT (-118.265586 34.043271)   284
POINT (-118.360102 34.071338)   269
POINT (-118.40816 33.943626)    241
```

to this desired outcome:

```
X-Axis        Y-Axis        count
-118.05425    34.1341       355
-118.244512   34.072581     337
-118.265586   34.043271     284
-118.360102   34.071338     269
-118.40816    33.943626     241
```

I have tried removing the word 'POINT', and both the brackets. But then I am met with an extra white space at the beginning of the column. I tried using:

```
count.columns = count.columns.str.lstrip()
```

But it was not removing the white space.

I was hoping to use this code to split the column:

```
count = pd.DataFrame(count.Location.str.split(' ',1).tolist(), 
                         columns = ['x-axis','y-axis'])
```

Since the space between both x and y axis could be used as the separator, but the white space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex pattern having capture groups:

```
df[['x-axis', 'y-axis']] = df.pop('Location').str.extract(r'\((\S+) (\S+)\)')
```

---

```
print(df)
   count       x-axis     y-axis
0    355   -118.05425    34.1341
1    337  -118.244512  34.072581
2    284  -118.265586  34.043271
3    269  -118.360102  34.071338
4    241   -118.40816  33.943626
```

Comment: This is a really noce solution!

Answer (score 5):

a quick solution can be:

```
(df['Location']
    .str.split(' ', 1)              # like what you did, 
    .str[-1]                        # select only lat,lon
    .str.strip('(')                 # remove open curly bracket
    .str.strip(')')                 # remove close curly bracket
    .str.split(' ', expand=True))   # expand to two columns
```

then you may rename column names using `.rename` or `df.columns = colnames`

Comment: Thanks! I managed to solve it using Lambda. I posted my solution.

Comment: @KieranCullinan, dont use lambda. It is costly